# Selecting actual length of field data rather field size

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim, dml

I have a scenario in which I have a table and there are two column in it.

```
Create Table Temp
(
  _id INT,
  Name VARCHAR(2000)
)

INSERT INTO Temp VALUES (1,'')
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES (2,'Mike Terri')

SELECT * FROM Temp
```

When I select by using `Ado.NET` in `VB` or `C#` it returns the length of "Name" column to 2000, I want to fetch only size of actual string contained, the thing which I am thing to do is to use Trim function, but its not possible in `Select *` scenario

Comment: SELECT LEN(Name) from Temp

Comment: @Rishabh : The thing is I am setting TextBox size on the size returned by this column, if this column has value it always return a 2000 length for the column, but I want it return actual string and trim of the white space remaining in the column

Comment: then `Select max(ltrim(rtrim(len(name)))) from temp`

Comment: But in Vb.Net, C# it DataSet's Object it tells Length = 2000, I want that to limited to Max number of characters in it that a column has in selection

Comment: @DareDevil that doesn't seem like the best practice. May I ask why you want the `DataSet` to reflect information on the data and not the schema?

Comment: Sorry but your question doesn't make sense.  WHAT returns the length? Why isn't trim available?  Maybe posting your .net code would be helpful

Comment: @ Matthew Haugen : Basically I have to dynamically draw Custom Grid, for that I need Columns Width So i can set the size while displaying, that's why I am fetching the size for the columns filed, but DataSet takes the schema width and always returns 2000

Comment: @Kevin In my debug window ,ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Name").Length , It shows 2000{Integer} in value column

Comment: @DareDevil, will ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Name").toSting().Length make sense?

Comment: @AK47 ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Name").toSting().Length will return the actual count but the schema count is always 2000, which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: @DareDevil, what exactly do you want?  People have given you several options that apparently solve your problem, but you keep rejecting them and insisting on doing the wrong thing and wanting it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATALENGTH` function as:

```
SELECT _id,
       Name,
       DATALENGTH(Rtrim(Ltrim(Name))) as Length 
FROM Temp
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Len function as follow:

```
SELECT *, LEN(Name) from Temp
```